# SPARK SQL CREATE VIEW

Tags: apache-spark, spark-thriftserver

I have noticed that there seems to be some max length of the create view statement.  Below is a SQL query I can run (select statement).  If I put a create view in front, it works as long as I limit the columns in the sub-query.  The view itself would only contain one column.  I have provided this for example.  I am running my sql through thrift server.  Is there any way to get around this issue?  Thanks in advance!

Working

```
select p from 
(
select p
from
(select p,concat(
p1,',',p2,',',p3,',',p4,',',p5,',',p6,',',p7,',',p8,',',p9,',',p10,',',p11,',',p12,',',p13,',',p14,',',p15,',',p16,',',p17,',',p18,',',p19,',',p20,',',
p21,',',p22,',',p23,',',p24,',',p25,',',p26,',',p27,',',p28,',',p29,',',p30,',',p31,',',p32,',',p33,',',p34,',',p35,',',p36,',',p37,',',p38,',',p39,',',p40,',',
p41,',',p42,',',p43,',',p44,',',p45,',',p46,',',p47,',',p48,',',p49,',',p50,',',p51,',',p52,',',p53,',',p54,',',p55,',',p56,',',p57,',',p58,',',p59,',',p60,',',
p61,',',p62,',',p63,',',p64,',',p65,',',p66,',',p67,',',p68,',',p69,',',p70,',',p71,',',p72,',',p73,',',p74,',',p75,',',p76,',',p77,',',p78,',',p79,',',p80,',',
p81,',',p82,',',p83,',',p84,',',p85,',',p86,',',p87,',',p88,',',p89,',',p90,',',p91,',',p92,',',p93,',',p94,',',p95,',',p96,',',p97,',',p98,',',p99,',',p100,',',
p101,',',p102,',',p103,',',p104,',',p105,',',p106,',',p107,',',p108,',',p109,',',p110,',',p111,',',p112,',',p113,',',p114,',',p115,',',p116,',',p117,',',p118,',',p119,',',p120,',',
p121,',',p122,',',p123,',',p124,',',p125,',',p126,',',p127,',',p128,',',p129,',',p130,',',p131,',',p132,',',p133,',',p134,',',p135,',',p136,',',p137,',',p138,',',p139,',',p140,',',
p141,',',p142,',',p143,',',p144,',',p145,',',p146,',',p147,',',p148,',',p149,',',p150,',',p151,',',p152,',',p153,',',p154,',',p155,',',p156,',',p157,',',p158,',',p159,',',p160,',',
p161,',',p162,',',p163,',',p164,',',p165,',',p166,',',p167,',',p168,',',p169,',',p170,',',p171,',',p172,',',p173,',',p174,',',p175,',',p176,',',p177,',',p178,',',p179,',',p180,',',
p181,',',p182,',',p183,',',p184,',',p185,',',p186,',',p187,',',p188,',',p189,',',p190,',',p191,',',p192,',',p193,',',p194,',',p195,',',p196,',',p197,',',p198,',',p199,',',p200,',',
p201,',',p202,',',p203,',',p204,',',p205,',',p206,',',p207,',',p208,',',p209,',',p210,',',p211,',',p212,',',p213,',',p214,',',p215,',',p216,',',p217,',',p218,',',p219,',',p220,',',
p221,',',p222,',',p223,',',p224,',',p225,',',p226,',',p227,',',p228,',',p229,',',p230,',',p231,',',p232,',',p233,',',p234,',',p235,',',p236,',',p237,',',p238,',',p239,',',p240,',',
p241,',',p242,',',p243,',',p244,',',p245,',',p246,',',p247,',',p248,',',p249,',',p250,',',p251,',',p252,',',p253,',',p254,',',p255,',',p256,',',p257,',',p258,',',p259,',',p260,',',
p261,',',p262,',',p263,',',p264,',',p265,',',p266,',',p267,',',p268,',',p269,',',p270,',',p271,',',p272,',',p273,',',p274,',',p275,',',p276,',',p277,',',p278,',',p279) vector
from table1) a
) c
```

Not working

```
CREATE VIEW TEST AS 
select p from 
(
select p
from
(select p,concat(
p1,',',p2,',',p3,',',p4,',',p5,',',p6,',',p7,',',p8,',',p9,',',p10,',',p11,',',p12,',',p13,',',p14,',',p15,',',p16,',',p17,',',p18,',',p19,',',p20,',',
p21,',',p22,',',p23,',',p24,',',p25,',',p26,',',p27,',',p28,',',p29,',',p30,',',p31,',',p32,',',p33,',',p34,',',p35,',',p36,',',p37,',',p38,',',p39,',',p40,',',
p41,',',p42,',',p43,',',p44,',',p45,',',p46,',',p47,',',p48,',',p49,',',p50,',',p51,',',p52,',',p53,',',p54,',',p55,',',p56,',',p57,',',p58,',',p59,',',p60,',',
p61,',',p62,',',p63,',',p64,',',p65,',',p66,',',p67,',',p68,',',p69,',',p70,',',p71,',',p72,',',p73,',',p74,',',p75,',',p76,',',p77,',',p78,',',p79,',',p80,',',
p81,',',p82,',',p83,',',p84,',',p85,',',p86,',',p87,',',p88,',',p89,',',p90,',',p91,',',p92,',',p93,',',p94,',',p95,',',p96,',',p97,',',p98,',',p99,',',p100,',',
p101,',',p102,',',p103,',',p104,',',p105,',',p106,',',p107,',',p108,',',p109,',',p110,',',p111,',',p112,',',p113,',',p114,',',p115,',',p116,',',p117,',',p118,',',p119,',',p120,',',
p121,',',p122,',',p123,',',p124,',',p125,',',p126,',',p127,',',p128,',',p129,',',p130,',',p131,',',p132,',',p133,',',p134,',',p135,',',p136,',',p137,',',p138,',',p139,',',p140,',',
p141,',',p142,',',p143,',',p144,',',p145,',',p146,',',p147,',',p148,',',p149,',',p150,',',p151,',',p152,',',p153,',',p154,',',p155,',',p156,',',p157,',',p158,',',p159,',',p160,',',
p161,',',p162,',',p163,',',p164,',',p165,',',p166,',',p167,',',p168,',',p169,',',p170,',',p171,',',p172,',',p173,',',p174,',',p175,',',p176,',',p177,',',p178,',',p179,',',p180,',',
p181,',',p182,',',p183,',',p184,',',p185,',',p186,',',p187,',',p188,',',p189,',',p190,',',p191,',',p192,',',p193,',',p194,',',p195,',',p196,',',p197,',',p198,',',p199,',',p200,',',
p201,',',p202,',',p203,',',p204,',',p205,',',p206,',',p207,',',p208,',',p209,',',p210,',',p211,',',p212,',',p213,',',p214,',',p215,',',p216,',',p217,',',p218,',',p219,',',p220,',',
p221,',',p222,',',p223,',',p224,',',p225,',',p226,',',p227,',',p228,',',p229,',',p230,',',p231,',',p232,',',p233,',',p234,',',p235,',',p236,',',p237,',',p238,',',p239,',',p240,',',
p241,',',p242,',',p243,',',p244,',',p245,',',p246,',',p247,',',p248,',',p249,',',p250,',',p251,',',p252,',',p253,',',p254,',',p255,',',p256,',',p257,',',p258,',',p259,',',p260,',',
p261,',',p262,',',p263,',',p264,',',p265,',',p266,',',p267,',',p268,',',p269,',',p270,',',p271,',',p272,',',p273,',',p274,',',p275,',',p276,',',p277,',',p278,',',p279) vector
from table1) a
) c
```

WORKING

```
CREATE VIEW TEST AS 
select p from 
(
select p
from
(select p,concat(
p1,',',p2,',',p3,',',p4,',',p5,',',p6,',',p7,',',p8,',',p9,',',p10,',',p11,',',p12,',',p13,',',p14,',',p15,',',p16,',',p17,',',p18,',',p19,',',p20,',',
p21,',',p22,',',p23,',',p24,',',p25,',',p26,',',p27,',',p28,',',p29,',',p30,',',p31,',',p32,',',p33,',',p34,',',p35,',',p36,',',p37,',',p38,',',p39,',',p40,',',
p41,',',p42,',',p43,',',p44,',',p45,',',p46,',',p47,',',p48,',',p49,',',p50,',',p51,',',p52,',',p53,',',p54,',',p55,',',p56,',',p57,',',p58,',',p59,',',p60,',',
p61,',',p62,',',p63,',',p64,',',p65,',',p66,',',p67,',',p68,',',p69,',',p70,',',p71,',',p72,',',p73,',',p74,',',p75,',',p76,',',p77,',',p78,',',p79,',',p80,',',
p81,',',p82,',',p83,',',p84,',',p85,',',p86,',',p87,',',p88,',',p89,',',p90,',',p91,',',p92,',',p93,',',p94,',',p95,',',p96,',',p97,',',p98,',',p99,',',p100,',') vector
from table1) a
) c
```

Comment: Solved!  Use SQL Squirrel instead with JDBC driver to connect and run queries.  I was using the Microsoft SPARK ODBC driver.  the JDBC one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use JDBC driver included with Spark.  I can compile view now.  I am using SQL

Use SQL Squirrel instead with JDBC driver to connect and run queries. I was using the Microsoft SPARK ODBC driver. the JDBC one works fine.